# Error 3075 usando un query select in Microsoft Accces

Tags: vba, ms-access

Intente hacer un query select que se trae los datos de una tabla pero da este error diciendo que falta un operador, que me parece extraño porque el query parece completo

Esta es mi forma, como lo subrayado en amarillo es un combobox con nombre Id_productos, lo que quiero es que ese combobox afecte al campo de texto que se llama Nombreitem, es el que esta abajo de Cantidad.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el query usado por el combobox, que esta dentro de "Origen de fila". Por cierto, como paso los datos del query a esa variable?

```
SELECT [Categorias Query].ID_Categoria, [Categorias Query].Categorias
FROM [Categorias Query]
ORDER BY [Categorias Query].[Categorias];
```

Este es el query que estoy intentando usar en el combobox independiente llamado Id_productos

```
Private Sub Id_productos_Change()
Dim SQL As String
Dim Id_producto As Integer

Id_producto = CDbl(Me.Id_productos.Value)

SQL = "SELECT Categorias" & _
             "FROM Categorias " & _
              "WHERE ID_Categoria = " & CStr(Id_producto)
 
DoCmd.RunSQL SQL

Me.Nombreitem.Value = Inventario.Nombreitem
End Sub
```

Esta es la tabla a la cual me trato de comunicar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si observas, no hay espacio en blanco entre estas dos líneas:  `SQL = "SELECT Categorias" & _` y  `"FROM Categorias " & _`, lo que estaría produciendo algo como esto: `SELECT CategoriasFROM Categorias ...` Prueba a corregir agregando un espacio en blanco: **`SQL = "SELECT Categorias " & _`**

Comment: Declaras tu ID como Integer. Ten en cuenta que a partir de algo más de 32.000, te dará error de desbordamiento.

Answer (score 2):

Veo varios problemas en tu código:

- Te faltan espacios, creo que te confunde la concatenación en varias líneas, pero la cadena SQL queda más o menos de esta forma: `'SELECT CategoriasFROM...'`, ¿ves el error allí?. Lo que te sugiero es:

  - que utilices [`MsgBox()`](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/msgbox-function-e23511c8-4157-4e09-93a6-ba9f1749f4c0) para poder *ver* el query que vas a mandar a la base de datos y verificar que esté bien.
  - que, como práctica general, inicies la cadena que concatenas en cada nueva línea con un espacio en blanco (a menos que tengas una buena razón para no hacerlo).
- Además de eso, estás declarando una variable como entero, y le asignas un Double que interpretas desde una cadena. Esto no es particularmente problemático, pero puedes ir directo a entero en la conversión, utilizando `CInt` y no `CDbl`.
- Finalmente, estás tratando de ejecutar una sentencia `select`, y eso no puede hacerse. `RunSQL` sirve para invocar sentencias que actualizan o borran datos, pero no para recuperar información. Si lo que quieres es obtener el valor de la descripción en una variable, utiliza un `recordset`, por ejemplo:

```
Private Sub Id_productos_Change()
  Dim SQL As String
  Dim Id_categoria As Integer
  Dim db As DAO.Database
  Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
  Dim NombreCategoria As String

  Id_categoria = CInt(Me.Id_productos.Value)

  SQL = "SELECT Categorias" & _
        " FROM Categorias " & _
        " WHERE ID_Categoria = " & CStr(Id_categoria)

  ' solo para estar seguros, si todo va bien, quita la llamada a MsgBox()
  MsgBox(SQL) 

  Set db = CurrentDb()
  Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset(SQL)

  If rs1.RecordCount > 0 Then
    rs1.MoveFirst
    NombreCategoria = rs1.Fields("Categorias")
    ' Acá tienes el nombre de la categoría en una variable, la muestro con MsgBox, 
    ' tu puedes utilizarla para lo que te convenga.
    MsgBox(NombreCategoria)
  End If
  rs1.Close
  set rs1 = Nothing
  set db = Nothing

  Me.Nombreitem.Value = Inventario.Nombreitem
End Sub
```

Comment: Me tiro un error 2342 en DoCmd.RunSQL SQL

Comment: No había caído en la cuenta de que se intenta ejecutar una sentencia `select`, ahora está listo, edité la respuesta.

Comment: Sigue tirando el mismo error. No sé que esta pasando

Comment: El código aún tenía la sentencia `RunSQL`, que recién eliminé en mi última edición. Quizás no te has dado cuenta, pero el código lo escribo aquí mismo en el editor. No espero que sea perfecto, si lees la explicación y prestas atención, podrías darte cuenta por ti mismo de algo como eso. La idea aquí es que aprendas.